# Easier way to edit multiple HTML files in Xcode?

Tags: html, xcode, edit

I have multiple HTML files in Xcode that I want to replace below:

```
<style type="text/css">
with
<style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
             font-family: MyFont;
             src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/AnmolUniBani.ttf')
        }
        body {
             font-family: MyFont;
        }
```

Please suggest me if there is any easier way to edit this in Xcode. Perhaps if I can do contains and replace.

Answer (score 0):

If you put them in a project together, you should be able to a global search and replace. I believe the keyboard shortcut is Shift-Option-Cmd-F by default.